# Increase TextView number one at a time (over time)

Tags: android, textview

I am interested in trying to implement a TextView with a number that climbs up or down when you add or subtract a number from it.

Example, start with 0.  When the user will open a dialog enter 5 and submit.  I then want the 0 to increase as such, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

If it was a larger number, I would want it to increase similar to that of an animation transition, where it starts off slow, gets faster (counting) and then slows down towards the end.  That would be similar to something like going from 0 to 100.

Has anyone seen anything like this implemented, or have the slightest idea of how that could work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I will be more than happy to clarify any if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something like this a while ago.

Things you need:
- Different textviews for each digit.
- Transition animation

```
<translate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="100"
 android:repeatMode="restart"
 android:repeatCount="infinite"
 android:fromYDelta="200%"
 android:toYDelta="-200%" >
</translate>
```

- Make those textView in a layout.

  ```
               <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                     <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_dollar"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:visibility="invisible"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:text="$"/>

                     <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_digit1"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:visibility="invisible"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:text="$"/>

                      <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_separator"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:visibility="invisible"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:text=","/>

                     <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_digit2"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:visibility="invisible"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:text="$"/>

                     <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_digit3"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:text="$"/>

                     <TextView 
                         android:id="@+id/tv_intro_digit4"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:textSize="20sp"
                         android:textStyle="bold"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:textColor="#333333"
                         android:text="0"/>



                 </LinearLayout>
  ```
- keep these textViews hidden initially.
- create animation in your java code

  ```
      Animation increasing_count_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.increasing_count)
  ```
- set animation listener on it and on animation end increase the number by 1 and update the textview using setText().
- you have to create an animation object for each digit.
- when user inputs number start animation

**** Caution : for large numbers mind that incrementing one digit at one time will take large time to reach the final number.

In case of small number eg 12. you can start by setting first digit as zero and increase text onAnimationEnd and when it reaches 9 make the second digit visible and continue.

In case of large number eg 400 / 4000, use handler to run a delayed animation.startAnimation function

```
 mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
        digit3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        digit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        digit3.setText("0");
        digit3.startAnimation(increasing_count_3);
       }
   }, 1500);
```

Hope you get my approach. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: What kind of transition animation did you use?  I am guessing I will need to determine the max # i will allow in my app.  For instance - 999,999.99 which would mean i'd need 10 TextView's for this method to work.  Now im just trying to understand how exactly the programming would work with this.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going to take a stab at this tomorrow and may contact you again through here if I need some additional help.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you are certain that you will need 10 textviews max then make layout as shown above. create a translation animation using the above code. the transition animation will make the number move from 200% below itself to 200% above itself. Due to restricted parent it will appear to be increasing from bottom to top like that at gas stations. For large numbers use handler method to start animation at your desired time interval, using above code of postDelayed. I was using the $ symbol hence i made two textviews visible at one time.